# App crashing on startup ONLY on Google Pixel with Android Nougat

Tags: java, android, google-pixel

I'm using Google Play Console to test my app before releasing it to the public and I'm getting a consistent crash on startup **only on Google Pixel devices running on Android Nougat(7.1).** Every other device runs the app without problems, including the same Google Pixel running on Android Oreo(8.0).

The log shows the following info:

```
D/AndroidRuntime(8360): Shutting down VM 11-15 13:14:46.176: 
D/AndroidRuntime(8360): --------- beginning of crash 
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360): Process: com.systemallica.gallery, PID: 8360
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.systemallica.gallery/com.systemallica.gallery.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360):     at com.systemallica.gallery.MainActivity.b(Unknown Source)
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360):     at com.systemallica.gallery.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
11-15 13:14:46.176: E/AndroidRuntime(8360):     ... 9 more
11-15 13:14:46.181: W/ActivityManager(1002):   Force finishing activity com.systemallica.gallery/.MainActivity
11-15 13:14:46.186: W/ActivityManager(1002):   Force finishing activity com.systemallica.gallery/.MainActivity
```

Full MainActivity source: https://pastebin.com/Ar5j2fEh

The MainActivity onCreate:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BOTH= 114;

@BindView(R.id.swipelayout) SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Check for sdk >= 23
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        // Check CAMERA and MEDIA permission
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BOTH);
            // When permissions are granted
        }else{
            setFABListener();
            loadFolders(columns);
        }
    }

    // Set on swipe refresh listener
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            startRefresh();
        }
    });

    // Change navBar colour
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        int app_primary = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.app_primary);
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(app_primary);
    }
}
}
```

I don't even know where to start debugging. Any idea of what the problem could be?

Comment: You haven't included any of the code for the methods in your `MainActivity` which are likely causing the issue. That log says the problem is the method `MainActivity.b()`, which looks like it is being obfuscated. You either need to de-obfuscate your logs, or run the app without obfuscation to see which method it is.

Comment: Please share full source code of MainActivity.Not enough information to figure out issue.

Comment: @Tanis.7x Okay I'll try to de-obfuscate the logs.

Comment: @PankajKantPatel Here you go: https://pastebin.com/Ar5j2fEh (sorry, it's a big activity)

Comment: What you really should do is deobfuscate the stack trace. That would point at the line where the issue is. The only thing I can see now that it's in a method called from onCreate.